# Node-RED input/output not showing

Tags: npm, node-red

I am new to node-red and i just installed it with npm on manjaro and i was wondering how to get the

[image: input/output categories]

in my Palette.

EDIT:

i installed it using npm from the [documentation](https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/local):
`npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red`

i executed the command at the home directory (~) and as far as am told those options should have been in the default packages. i didn't do anything else besides running node-red locally.

Comment: What makes you think they should be in those groups? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66781692/edit) the question to include a link to the actual node you installed.

Comment: Also include the details of EXACTLY how you installed the node, what command you ran and what directory you were in when you ran it. Also what you did after that before looking in the palette

Answer (score 0):

After all i was using a newer version on Node-red and the categories and some names are a slightly different. Thank you very much!